# Deploy Asp.net Application on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I am deploying Asp.net Application at IIS server getting this error, But when i  run this application my server its fine and give no problem .I have one html static web site in  that html site folder i made tool folder, In that tool folder i deploy my asp.net application ,

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
     Runtime Error

  Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

 Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


 <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   </system.web>
   </configuration>

   Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


  <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

  <configuration>
   <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
 </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Here is my Web.config

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow roles="administrators" />
<deny users="*" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='|DataDirectory|\mfaridalam1.accdb'; Persist Security Info=False"/>
  </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
    </system.web>
       <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

       <system.web>
       <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </httpHandlers>
     </system.web>
     <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
     <location path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd">
      <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
      </system.web>

      </location>


    </configuration>
```

Here is SS of error
[image]

Comment: can you try changing the custom error mode to "Off" in web config temporarily, just to check whats the actual error

Comment: i dont have that setting in my web . config file

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter, yes my bad :)

Comment: @JayZee, can you please take a look at this article it might help  http://forums.iis.net/t/1187726.aspx/1

Comment: @Mac its really complicated for me to understand please tell me if you have solution

Comment: @Jay Zee Open IIS Manager (Start -> Run -> inetmgr.exe).  Find your site on the left.  In the center, choose "Error Pages".  On the right choose "Edit Feature Settings".  Change "Custom Errors" to "Detailed Errors". Refresh the page, and you should receive the actual error that's occurring. Send that to us.

Comment: If you don't have IIS access to the server you're deploying too, you will need to add that <customErrors mode="off" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm" /> line between these two lines your web.config:  <system.web>[Insert here]<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try deleting the website from iis and restarting iis? at the same time clean your project and rebuild it. then try publishing it in the right location. Are you creating virtual directory?

Comment: i can build my project here on my laptop not at server i can delete and copy it again but be4 deploying my project i already build it and there was no error

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a general error which does not give us details of what went wrong.

Possible checks you can do is:

```
1. Check web.config and make Custom Error Mode off
2. Try to host application locally
3. Check all files have been deployed on server or not?
4. View page locally on server
5. Add stacktrace to find exact issue.
6. Do logging on request
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have access on server and using windows server, try to open the website in browser and if it fails then look into Event Viewer -> Windows Logs of windows to see the error.